# How configure router for jenkins node

Tags: networking, jenkins, router, portforwarding

Hope you're doing well. I need your help with configuring local network or rather router settings. So, within my network I have two machines running OSX El Capitan and I want to use them as a Jenkins nodes. Jenkins is running on digitalocean so it's outside my network. With one node it's kinda easy - I've used DMZ and binded it to node's ip address, but can't have 2 dmz (lol). I guess I need to open some ports and then configure node, but have no clue how to do that. Appreciate any help or hints.

Best,
radek

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins has a built-in SSH client implementation that it can use to talk to remote sshd and start a slave agent. This is the most convenient and preferred method for Unix slaves, which normally has sshd out-of-the-box. Click Manage Jenkins, then Manage Nodes, then click "New Node." In this set up, you'll supply the connection information (the slave host name, user name, and ssh credential). Note that the slave will need the master's public ssh key copied to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

Reference : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds

Comment: thank you for you answer, but that's not what I'm looking for - I know how to configure slave. What I don't know is how to expose node's machines so they are visible from outside LAN, and can be connected. Do you see my point now?

Comment: Hi, 
You need to configure port forwarding for your router. External link on how to do this : http://helpdeskgeek.com/networking/configure-router-for-remote-desktop/ I'll suggest you to open only those ports which are required by jenkins e.g. Port: 22